# Bind EditorFor to Array of string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

After trying with a more sophisticated viewmodel with no success I came to use a viewmodel which is like this:

```
public class CarteExpressViewModel
{
    public string[] LesEntrees;      
    public string[] LesPlats; 

    public CarteExpressViewModel()
    {
        LesEntrees = new string[]{ "", "", "", "", "", "" };
        LesPlats = new string[]{ "", "", "", "", "", "" };
    }
}
```

I pass the viewModel in my create method of my controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    CarteExpressViewModel carteExpressViewModel = new CarteExpressViewModel();
    return View(carteExpressViewModel);
}
```

Problem is I can see the input value if I use a `FormCollection` as parameter of my Post create method but everything is null if i use the viewmodel
My view is line this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.LesEntrees.Length; i++)
{

    <div class="editor-label ">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LesEntrees[i], "Entrée n°" + (i + 1).ToString(), new { @class = " express_input_label" })
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field  ">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LesEntrees[i], new { @class = " express-input" })
    </div>
}
```

I can't see what's wrong but sure something should.

Answer (score 1):

You set up the variables as *fields*, not properties. Change them to:

```
public string[] LesEntrees { get; set; }
public string[] LesPlats { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to Chris Pratt answer, yes I should use properties but it's not enough since there is a problem with array 
(see [http://forums.asp.net/t/1597890.aspx?Collection+is+read+only+Arrays+in+models](http://forums.asp.net/t/1597890.aspx?Collection%20is%20read%20only%20Arrays%20in%20models))
So I came back to my less simple viewmodel which use Lists and this one works.....